# i want to print yes if the reverse number and first number are equal. And no if they are not. How can i?

Tags: c

reverse numbers in c:

i want to print yes if the reverse number and first number are equal. And no if they are not. How can i?

[code link](https://onlinegdb.com/rJwDEOCnv)

Comment: how about: `if (n == r) printf("yes\n"); else printf("no\n");`?

Comment: It doesn't answer correctly

Comment: Print the value of `n` after the `while` and you should get the answer.

Comment: @mch Turn that into an explained answer and have my upvote.

Comment: pary [edit] your question according to [ask] and have my upvote.

Comment: Pity, your question was closed and risks being deleted if not improved. That would be bad for you (I can link info if your doubt that) and would lose a helpful fellow user some earned reward for their trouble. Please improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare the original value with the reversed one. You can do it like that:

```
if (n == r) printf("yes\n"); else printf("no\n");
```

But you are changing the value of `n` during the loop, therefore you have to copy the original value to another variable and use the new variable in the `while` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n, r = 0, x;

  printf("Enter a number to reverse\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  x = n; //here we make a copy of the original value
  while (x != 0)
  {
    r = r * 10;
    r = r + x%10;
    x = x/10;
  }

  printf("Reverse of the number = %d\n", r);
  if (n == r) printf("yes\n"); else printf("no\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Program Explanation

1. Take the number which you have to reverse as the input and store it in the variable num.
2. Copy the input number to the another variable temp.
3. Firstly initialize the variable reverse to zero.
4. Obtain the remainder of the input number.
5. Multiply the variable reverse with 10 and add the Obtained remainder to it and store the result in the same variable.
6. Obtain the quotient of the input number and considering this as input number repeat the steps as mentioned above until the obtained quotient becomes zero.
7. When it becomes zero, using if,else statement check whether the reversed number is equal to original number or not.
8. If it is equal, then print the output as “Yes”, otherwise print the output as “No”.


    #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
       int num, temp, remainder, reverse = 0;
        printf("Enter an integer \n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        /* original number is stored at temp */
        temp = num;
        while (num > 0)
        {
            remainder = num % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            num /= 10;
        }
        printf("Given number is = %d\n", temp);
        printf("Its reverse is  = %d\n", reverse);
        if (temp == reverse)
            printf("Yes \n");
        else
            printf("No \n");
    }
    
    Case:1
    Enter an integer
    6789
    Given number is = 6789
    Its reverse is  = 9876
    No
     
    Case:2
    Enter an integer
    58085
    Given number is = 58085
    Its reverse is  = 58085
    Yes
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry, but copying the explanation from another existing answer is not really what I meant. Please try to make your own contribution.

Comment: I am not copying answer, i just add explanation :)

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that while your code is different your (now removed) explanation is noticably similar to the explanation in (former versions of) the other answer? Also currently you are back to non-explained code-only answer....

Comment: Did you test your code? I did, tried 12321, expected "Yes" but got "No".

Comment: Your explanation now describes almost line by line what the code does. It does however not explain how the shown code solves OPs problem and what that problem actually was. Apart from the fact that I think it does not actually solve the problem.

Comment: I think this is correct, First time i don't test it, Thank You :)

Comment: "I think this correct." gives an impression of guessing. If you would explain your code, how it works, the meaning of each variable and how it solves the problem, then it would give a much more confident and helpful impression. See my first comment...

Comment: Again you have added a description of what exactly the code does. But that is not an explanation of why it solves the problem. In my opinion it does not even explain how it works. Your description is what the code itself already shows to any C programmer. Try to answer the "Why?" instead of the "How?" in painstaking detail.

Comment: Thank you :) For Guiding

Comment: Please tell me with example

Comment: I told you in several different wordings. And I linked to an explanation in my first comment. For an example see the other answer, which I did upvote for providing an explanation of why it solves the problem and of the core of how it does so. It even explicitly explains the mistake you had in an earlier code version. I cannot do better than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226291/discussion-between-amit-joshi-and-yunnosch).